# Spotify API: add tracks to playlist: error parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests, spotify

I'm trying to bulk add songs to a playlist. I cannot for the life of me find the difference between the API documentation and what I am sending, but it errors anyway. Here is the function I'm using and how I'm calling it:

```
def addToPlaylist(songs, playlistUrl, positions = None):
    data = { 'uris': songs }
    if position != None:
        data.update({ 'position': position })

    headers = authHeader.copy()
    headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    print(headers)
    print(json.dumps(data))

    req = requests.post(playlistUrl, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(data))
    if req.status_code != 201:
        print('Error: Request returned status code {}. Returned: {}'.format(req.status_code, req.text))

songs = ["spotify:track:1i1fxkWeaMmKEB4T7zqbzK", "spotify:track:2VKqMKKCFhTPczQb10TMKB", "spotify:track:7Gl9cKtVjRN6KHNMfV1gD3"]
url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/username/playlists/2...Q/tracks"
addToPlaylist(songs, url, 0)
```

The two debug print()s tell me the following:

```
{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer BlahblahblA'}
{"position": 0, "uris": ["spotify:track:1i1fxkWeaMmKEB4T7zqbzK", "spotify:track:2VKqMKKCFhTPczQb10TMKB", "spotify:track:7Gl9cKtVjRN6KHNMfV1gD3"]}
```

The error output tells me this:

```
Error: Request returned status code 400. Returned: {
  "error" : {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Error parsing JSON."
  }
}
```

When changing the URL to `http://localhost:3001` and listening with netcat `nc -l -p 3001`, I can see the following request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 0:3001
Accept: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: python-requests/2.11.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer BlahblahblA
Content-Length: 145

{"position": 0, "uris": ["spotify:track:1i1fxkWeaMmKEB4T7zqbzK", "spotify:track:2VKqMKKCFhTPczQb10TMKB", "spotify:track:7Gl9cKtVjRN6KHNMfV1gD3"]}
```

I might think the body should be URL-encoded, even though that's not what the Content-Type header mentions, but another requests (the `DELETE` to delete songs from a playlist) works and there I don't use url encoding.

Finally [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/) mentions the following:

> ```
> POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> `Content-Type`: Required if URIs are passed in the request body, otherwise ignored. The content type of the request body: `application/json`
>
> [...]
>
> `uris`: array of Spotify URI strings | Optional. A JSON array of the Spotify track URIs to add. For example:
>   `{"uris": ["spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh",
>   "spotify:track:1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M"]}`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While writing this post, it caught my attention that the `position` parameter was not supposed to be in the request body. It has to be in the URI parameters. Testing this, it works.

In my defense, Spotify's error suggested the JSON data was not syntactically correct, which was not the case. This took entirely too much time.

This works:

```
if position is not None:
    playlistUrl += '?position=' + str(position)
```

Instead of `data.update({'position': position})` (<= this is wrong).